# Konva Stage size

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

In Konva, does Stage size really matter?

Because I can zoom in almost infinitely, and if a large stage does become slow, why not just make all the elements really small and fit 2000 objects into a stage which is technically 100x100?

I'm asking because I am creating a designer, and the final product has to be serialized and re-rendered later on different devices.

And I don't know if I should implement rules now to make it better for the final render (like size limits or something), or if I can just build the designer and render the final product as is?

Comment: The HTML5 canvas, and Konva, use vector graphics which are math-based and can scale to any size (theoretically). The issue comes where the theory touches the real world and you ask the browser to render the image built on the canvas. That comes down to old fashioned image drawing in the code of the browser. If you scale that image then there's some additional math but on a single draw it's a low overhead. Use the performance tips at the konva site. https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks for the reply, but is the "large" stage they're referring to a stage with a large area (like a 5000x5000 stage) or a stage with a lot of elements on it?

Comment: The canvas is drawn in memory and transferred to the surface that you see. Dimensions do have effect but mostly browsers are optimised for that. A canvas also consumes memory  while it exists.  If you have a small 100 x 100 canvas and scale it 10 times the drawing cost for the system is the same as a 1000 x 1000 canvas. With vector graphics scale is conceptual. Only when you render the drawing does scale have a meaning to the processor doing the work.  Outside of listening for events etc, the work burden it has to do is drawing the dots that you see. Read the performance tips.